# VS Code extension code unable to find JSON path

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to create a vs code extension that requires (or imports ;)) to read data from a local JSON file. I've kept the JSON in the root folder (same folder where I have my `extension.js`, `package.json`, `.gitignore`, etc). My code uses `fs` package to read the JSON file, but when I run the command in constructor, I get the following error,

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'fieldIds.json'
```

I read somewhere that the file path is relative to the folder from where node starts. I'm not sure from which folder node starts when I run my VS Code. But if I place my JSON in that folder, then should this work? How do I specify that I want to run the JSON from a specific path only (eg, Desktop?).

I tried to move my JSON file to the same folder as VS Code editors `settings.json`, but that didn't work either.

```
/Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/Code/User
```

Here's what my folder structure looks like

[image]

...and here's the code from extension

```
const vscode = require('vscode')
const fs = require('fs')

function activate (context) {
  // 'fieldIds.json' not found    
  const json = fs.readFile('fieldIds.json', 'utf8', (res) => console.log(res))
  console.log(JSON.stringify(json))

  ...
  context.subscriptions.push(...)
}
```

Help.

Comment: The current directory is not what you think it is.  Consider using `require.resolve()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make sure your **current working directory** is the same as where `fieldIds.json` is placed. Because the `fs` module eventually reads files from the current working directory.

If you really want to read a file in the same directory, consider using the following code:

```
const path = require('path')

...

fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "fieldIds.json"), "utf8")
```

The above code snippet will find `fieldIds.json` that is placed in the **same directory** with `extension.js` since `__dirname` is the path of the currently executing script.